# pyinstaller create binary from python3 file, error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I try to create python binary from python3 file with pyinstaller, but it failled and the error message as below, can anyone give me some suggestion? thanks.

```
user@user:~ /Pyinstaller3/pyinstaller-python3$ **python3.4 pyinstaller.py -F /home/austinlin/programTest/translate0918_1.py**
67 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.0.dev
67 INFO: Python: 3.4.3
67 INFO: Platform: Linux-3.2.0-90-generic-pae-i686-with-Ubuntu-12.04-precise
67 INFO: wrote /home/austinlin/tools/Pyinstaller3/pyinstaller-python3/translate0918_1/translate0918_1.spec
68 INFO: UPX is not available.
69 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with /home/austinlin/programTest
69 INFO: checking Analysis
76 INFO: checking PYZ
79 INFO: checking PKG
79 INFO: Building because toc changed
80 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyinstaller.py", line 18, in <module>
    run()
  File "/home/austinlin/tools/Pyinstaller3/pyinstaller-python3/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 99, in run
    run_build(opts, spec_file, pyi_config)
  File "/home/austinlin/tools/Pyinstaller3/pyinstaller-python3/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 47, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **opts.__dict__)
  File "/home/austinlin/tools/Pyinstaller3/pyinstaller-python3/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 734, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/home/austinlin/tools/Pyinstaller3/pyinstaller-python3/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 677, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 28, in <module>
  File "/home/austinlin/tools/Pyinstaller3/pyinstaller-python3/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 421, in __init__
    strip_binaries=self.strip, upx_binaries=self.upx,
  File "/home/austinlin/tools/Pyinstaller3/pyinstaller-python3/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 232, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/home/austinlin/tools/Pyinstaller3/pyinstaller-python3/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 153, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/home/austinlin/tools/Pyinstaller3/pyinstaller-python3/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 300, in assemble
    pylib_name = os.path.basename(bindepend.get_python_library_path())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/posixpath.py", line 139, in basename
    i = p.rfind(sep) + 1

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

**But if I use python python2.7 pyinstaller.py -F python2file.py, it work fine**

Comment: Perhaps you can report this to `pyinstaller` team instead

Comment: I get the same error when using pyinstaller on my project with Python 3.5. I haven't tried other versions of Python yet. I can't find this issue reported to PyInstaller yet.

Comment: It looks similar (but not identical) to this pyinstaller issue: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1739 for which the advice is that it's been fixed, but not released yet, so use the latest development version.

Comment: I still get the same problem using the latest development version of pyinstaller.

Comment: and I get the same problem using the latest development version of pyinstaller on a tiny sample "main.py" script - so it doesn't seem to be related to my project, but to be something in my environment, or a bug in pyinstaller.

Comment: But everything works fine using Python3.4 (all the above was with 3.5)

Comment: Did you ever get this working under Python 3.5?